# Can stepping discs transport a functioning stasis field?

Tags: larry-niven, known-space

In Larry Niven's Known Space universe, *stepping discs* teleport matter from a sending disc to a receiving disc.  Teleportation occurs at the speed of light.  The sending and receiving discs must have similar velocity vectors or the object transferred will experience the kinetic energy change as a temperature difference.  Stepping discs can compensate for small velocity differences without heating the teleported object.  We know from *The Ringworld Throne* that a stepping disc can also pass coherent radiation such as a laser beam.

In the same universe, *stasis fields* are regions of retarded time.  Time passes within the field  thousands or even billions of times slower than outside, depending on the field.

Since we don't know how stepping discs or stasis fields work, we have no way of knowing if they would work together.  **Has an operating stasis field ever been teleported by a stepping disc?**  A citation from any of the published Known Space works would be an acceptable basis for an answer, including the somewhat apocryphal Man-Kzin Wars stories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Spoilers follow for *Destroyer of Worlds*.

In *Destroyer of Worlds* Sigmund Ausfaller and Kirsten Quinn-Kovacs were evacuated from the badly damaged starship *Don Quixote* inside personal stasis fields.  The stasis fields were used to preserve life after Sigmund and Kirsten miraculously survived being roasted alive by the barely shielded exhaust of a fusion-driven Belter singleship.  Stepping discs were used to enter and leave the wrecked *Don Quixote* after Eric Huang-Mbeke performed a dangerous EVA to reach the ship and install an initial receiving disc.